# Float:left does not give me the correct gallery I want

Tags: css

[image: Grid that I want]

Currently trying to build a gallery page for a client's website and I've noticed that a simple float:left does not give me what i'm looking for.

What I want is for the images to line up perfectly regardless of their size as the images that I have supplied are all in different sizes.

```
.gallery img {
    margin:0 !important;
    border:1px solid white;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
```

That's the code that i'm using & the website is responsive.

Comment: can you please post the html too..

Answer (score 0):

use `height: auto;` and `max-width: 100%;`

```
.gallery img {
    margin:0 !important;
    border:1px solid white;

    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```